# getting null pointer exception with Firebase Auth. Have updated dependencies. downgraded, still not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference.

I have tested downgrading dependencies, cleaning project.
My internet connection is good. But the app crashes every time it launches.

New projects i start get the same problem after some few successful logins. :(

My Code:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    //firebase
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    authListner();


    initList();

    String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //login credentials
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

}
```

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        //Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    //If your minSdkVersion is lower than 21
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'

    // ButterKnife (for code brevity)
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //...

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Logcat:

```
07-16 08:39:33.014 2030-2030/? E/art: Failed to send JDWP packet APNM to debugger (-1 of 99): Broken pipe
07-16 08:39:33.187 2030-2047/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-16 08:39:35.396 2030-2030/com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons, PID: 2030
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons/com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.job.carwash_getfreewashescoupons.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6124)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code in onCreate is assuming that a user is already logged in at the time the activity is started:

```
String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

[`getCurrentUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) returns null when there is no logged in user.  You shouldn't assume that the user is logged in when an activity starts.  Use a listener to know when the user is logged in, then get their uid.

Comment: Turns out to handle edge cases. You need a auth listener in onCreate before event onStart.

Comment: Typically you manage your listeners in start/stop.  If you need to check if there's a logged in user immediately using getCurrentUser, you have to check for null.

Comment: yeah. Another issues in using the pre-built firebase UI. Should you include both gradle dependencies of say firebaseui auth and also firebase auth;  firebaseui: firestore and firestore. Or should you only use the firebaseui dependencies only?

Comment: This sounds like a whole new different question to ask.